# Singly linked list implementation in Scala

Tags: scala

What could be a better implementation, following the Scala way of doing it?

```
class Node(itemValue: Object, nextItem:Node){
  val value = itemValue
  val next = nextItem
}

class MyList() {
  var start: Node =null

  def add(value:Object){
    val cache = start
    this.start = new Node(value,cache)
  }

  def print:Unit  = {
    var n = start;
    println(n.value)
    while(n != null){
      println(n.value)
      n = n.next;
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list is just a wrapper for an element that also contains a pointer to another list, thus its definition is straightforward:

```
scala> abstract class MyList[+A]
defined class MyList

scala> case class MyCons[A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]
defined class MyCons

scala> case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]
defined object MyNil

scala> val xs = MyCons(1, MyCons(2, MyCons(3, MyNil)))
xs: MyList[Int] = MyCons(1,MyCons(2,MyCons(3,MyNil)))

scala> xs.head
res2: Int = 1

scala> xs.tail
res3: MyList[Int] = MyCons(2,MyCons(3,MyNil))
```

This list is completely immutable. Because of the polymorphic type `A` it can take any type of element and because it is covariant `+A`, it can also take the subtypes of an element:

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> class X extends T
defined class X

scala> val xs: MyList[T] = MyCons(new X, MyNil)
xs: MyList[T] = MyCons(X@56a13ea6,MyNil)
```

The covariant nature of type `A` also allows the definition of `MyNil`, which would not be possible otherwise because it is parameterized with type `Nothing`, Scalas bottom type.

This single linked list definition is also the actual implementation of type `List` in the stdlib of Scala, although this implementation contains some more `optimization` details and `MyCons` is called `::`.

If you also want to access the members `head` and `tail` when you only have type `MyList` instead of the more concrete type `MyCons` then you have to declare them directly in the supertype:

```
abstract class MyList[+A] {
  def head: A
  def tail: MyList[A]
}

case class MyCons[A](head: A, tail: MyList[A]) extends MyList[A]

case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing] {
  def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("MyNil.head")
  def tail = throw new NoSuchElementException("MyNil.tail")
}
```

Comment: thanks for the wonderful explanation, but is it required to always have a immutable List implementation, what if i need to dynamically add close to millions of data in the list by parsing some text file? won't it would be good to have a mutable list which can have O(1) complexity for add

Comment: the prepend operation is O(1). And if you need to append, then you should use a different data structure. At least when you want to stay functional.

Comment: Prepends plus a destructive reverse at the end will get you pretty good performance, right?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga prepend+reverse is O(n). For a lot of cases that is not pretty good performance.

Comment: Agreed its a factor of two worse, but simply prepending to build the list is O(n) too.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga prepend is O(1) when the list is immutable

Comment: Constructing a list out of N elements using prepend is O(N). Reversing that same list afterwards is another O(N). So the whole thing is O(N)… Just a factor of 2x separates the performance characteristics.